# Accessing object's getter method wrapped inside Map with JSP

Tags: java, jsp, dictionary, jstl

I am trying to figure out how to iterate over ConcurrentHashMap that is holding string as key and Object with getter methods.

Here is the class which object is stored in a map as value.

```
public class ServiceStats {

    public int unprocessedItems;
    public int processedItems;

    /**
     * @return the unprocessedItems
     */
    public int getUnprocessedItems() {
        return unprocessedItems;
    }

    /**
     * @param unprocessedItems the unprocessedItems to set
     */
    public void setUnprocessedItems(int unprocessedItems) {
        this.unprocessedItems = unprocessedItems;
    }

    /**
     * @return the processedItems
     */
    public int getProcessedItems() {
        return processedItems;
    }

    /**
     * @param processedItems the processedItems to set
     */
    public void setProcessedItems(int processedItems) {
        this.processedItems = processedItems;
    }

}
```

Servlet is sending data to the JSP like this.

```
@Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
            IOException {

        ConcurrentHashMap<String, ServiceStats> serviceStatsMap = stats.getServiceStats();

        request.setAttribute("stats", serviceStatsMap);    

        request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/jsp/stats.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
```

The iteration should be like this:

```
<c:forEach var="entry" items="${stats}">
   ${entry.key}, ${entry.value.getvaluefromgettermethod} 
</c:forEach>
```

How can I access object that is map's value and then access getter method inside that object?

And do I have to import my class in JSP like this or is this unnecessary?

```
<%@ page import="com.company.ServiceStats"%>
```

Comment: What do you think happens here `${entry.key}` ?

Comment: @AleksandrM If the `String` value comes from a user entered field, what happens is a potential [Cross-site scripting (XSS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) vulnerability.

Comment: @Amit.rk3 Thank you! It is working now. Didn't expect this to be so easy :)

Comment: Great.. glad it helped. will post it as answer. Please accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to access property `unprocessedItems` of object of type `ServiceStats`, since it has a proper getter, `${entry.value.unprocessedItems}` should suffice, also import is not needed.